# SPSS - sum of squares change radically with slight model changes in ANOVA?

Tags: st.statistics

I have noticed that the sum of squares in my models can change fairly radically with even the slightest adjustment to my models. Is this normal? I'm using SPSS 16, and both models presented below used the same data and variables with only one small change - categorizing one of the variables as either a 2 level or 3 level variable.

Details - using a 2 x 2 x 6 mixed model ANOVA with the 6 being the repeated measure i get the following in the between group analysis

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Source    | Type III SS |  df  |  MS       |  F      |  Sig
------------------------------------------------------------
intercept | 4086.46     |  1   | 4086.46   | 104.93  |  .000
X         |  224.61     |  1   |  224.61   |   5.77  |  .019
Y         |    2.60     |  1   |    2.60   |    .07  |  .80
X by Y    |   19.25     |  1   |   19.25   |    .49  |  .49
Error     | 2570.40     | 66   |   38.95   |
```

Then, when I use the exact same data but a slightly different model in which variable Y has 3 levels instead of 2 levels I get the following

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Source    | Type III SS |  df  |  MS       |  F      |  Sig
------------------------------------------------------------
intercept | 3603.88     |  1   | 3603.88   |  90.89  |  .000
X         |  171.89     |  1   |  171.89   |   4.34  |  .041
Y         |   19.23     |  2   |    9.62   |    .24  |  .79
X by Y    |   17.90     |  2   |   17.90   |    .80  |  .80
Error     | 2537.76     | 64   |   39.65   |
```

I don't understand why variable X would have a different sum of squares simply because variable Y gets devided up into 3 levels instead of 2. This is also the case in the within groups analysis too.

Please help me understand :D

Thank you in advance

Pat

Comment: Pat, I suspect you're at the wrong site for this question and are unlikely to get a good answer.  We don't currently have many mathematicians here who are interested in statistics, but even if we did this question looks more like a practical question that you'd need to ask a scientist who uses statistics rather than a theoretical question of interest to mathematicians.  That said, I'm not going to vote to close because I'd rather wait and see if we turn out to have an expert show up (who can then answer the question or explain better why it's not right for the site).

Comment: Thank for your comment Noah, I see what you mean about this being more of a practical question than a theoretical one. I had also posted this question over at stackoverflow which is more of a practical problem focused QandA site (albeit also not very statistics related ;P) and I got an answer over there this morning

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709745/spss-sum-of-squares-change-radically-with-slight-model-changes-in-anova

Thanks to everyone who read this question and voted for it. I'll be sure to be back here with my more theoretical questions in the future :D

Cheers,

Pat