# statistical analysis between 3 groups of data - what is the approptiate post hoc test for them?

Tags: st.statistics

I  measured one dependent variable between three groups of data (control, group1, group2).The result of t-test indicates significant difference between control and group 1 (p vale =.04), control and group 2(p value .01), but not significant between group 2 and group 3.Do I still need to use the post hoc test? If so, which test is the most appropriate?

Comment: Kamran, I suspect you're at the wrong site for this question and are unlikely to get a good answer. We don't currently have many mathematicians here who are interested in statistics, but even if we did this question looks more like a practical question about scientific conventions rather than a theoretical question of interest to mathematicians. A similar question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22532/ did not get any answers.  You and Pat could discuss whether there's a community for a statistics SE site, but I do not think MO is the place for that since we're mathematicians not scientists.

Comment: There is a proposal for a statistics SE site here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/

Answer (score 3):

If you've got more than two groups, don't use t-tests (due to the multiple comparisons trap). Use a one-way ANOVA instead (based on an F-test). Then if you want a post-hoc test after that, use Tukey's HSD.